# Performing search on multiple attributes in an object list

Tags: java, search

I need to implement a search method on a large number of objects. The strategy is the following:
There are two classes, say,

```
A{
String a1,
String a2,
...
}
and
B{
String b1,
String b2,
...
}
```

and two `ArrayLists` with objects of each type.
I need to find an `A` object where `A.a1 == B.b1`. If none is found, I need to find an `A` object where `A.a2 == B.b2` and so on.. (Here `==` stands for value-based equality as there may be attributes of other types)

What is the best way of making this as fast as possible? The only thing I could think of so far (besides iterating over arrays) is to create a number of HashMaps with attribute values as keys and Object references as values.

Is there a better way of solving this?

Comment: So do you need Reference based equality or value based equality?

Comment: I need value-based equality. The idea with HashMaps was to take an attribute `A.a1` and see if there is a `map.get(A.a1)` object which is of class `B`. Then do smth with this `b` object

Comment: Sorry, I am not an expert in this and mine is just brain storming: how about using a nosql java db? An in memory nosql db might worth trying how fast it is compared to your implementation. The code would also be cleaner.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should choose the HashMap way. The lookup is very efficient because of the hashs. And the memory overhead shouldn't be dramatic as only references are stored in the different Maps.

Comment: Well, I think this is what I'm going to stick with.

Answer (score 1):

What I think is you can achieve this in single loop. While iterating also check if other condition is true and store such objects. If you end up not finding `A.a1.equals(B.b1)` you have `A.a2.equals(B.b2)` so no need for additional loop.

```
 initalize object to store A.a2.equals(B.b2)
 for(size)
  { 
     if(A.a1.equals(B.b1))
      {
       //Found break;
      }
     else if(A.a2.equals(B.b2))
       {
        //Store this since if we end up not finding then we can use this
       }
  }
```

Comment: Well, yes, but will iterating over the entire array be actually faster than a HashMap search? Especially when there are lots of objects to be compared. Won't this be like `O(m*n)`, where `m, n` are the list sizes?

Comment: @svz No. It will never be. But there is cost associated while populating so you can afford cost at populating time then you can choose Hashmap

Answer (score -1):

Tried my best digging into the [Apache BeanUtils](http://commons.apache.org/beanutils/v1.8.3/apidocs/org/apache/commons/beanutils/BeanUtils.html) and all I could find for you is this. Instead of using reflection API/getters on each of the fields in your class, you could try to load the entire bean into a map in one shot using

`BeanUtils.describe(Object bean)`  - returns a `Map`

Comment: How does this answer the question?

Comment: If HashMap comparison is the option that we are looking at,this just makes the conversion easier.

Comment: `describe` creates a Map of ONE object with variableName=value tupels. The OP has a List of `A`s and `B`s presumably. Each *List* has to be transformed to a Map.